# how to implement traceroute without using TTL?

Tags: traceroute

how to implement traceroute without using TTL?

This is an interview question.
We all knew Traceroute uses TTL to get the routing path.
The question is how to implement traceroute without using TTL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory you could send a packet with [IP option 7](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip/option007.htm) set (record route).  This would return the path the packet took to the destination.

In practice this option is not widely supported, which is exactly why traceroute uses TTL.